# Program is saving every time the user presses enter, and spitting it out when cin is called

Tags: c++, winapi, cin

This is actually related to another question I asked, but i'v narrowed down the problem and rewrote the program to be cleaner and more barebones.

The main function passes the user to a menu where they can select what they wanna do. Problem is, that every time they press the return key, it seems to log that input into the cin buffer. When the user finally makes a choice and gets passed to the appropriate function, it spits out all the enter keys they hit which can cause it to skip through the process. This is pretty annoying, especially since I wanna use VK_RETURN for the selection.

Now, I could just stick a bunch of cin.clear() and cin.ignore()'s everywhere, but from what I understand, that's bad practice. Also, it messes with the program because it forces the user to hit the enter key an extra time to get off that line and messes with formatting.

Is there a way around this? Or is cin.clear() and cin.ignore my only hope?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

#include "menu_GUI.h"

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    std::string selection;  //user selection for selector menu
    std::string address;    //address to send funds to
    int amount;             //amount of funds to send

    std::string password;   //password for wallet encryption

    menu_GUI menu;  //object for menu_GUI class

    while(running)
    {
        selection = menu.mainMenu();    //collect users selection from the menu_GUI class selector function

        if(selection == "send")
        {
            address = menu.askAddress(address);    //collects the address the user wants to send funds to
            if(address != "cancel"){amount = menu.askAmount(amount);}     //collects the amount the user wants to send if they don't cancel
            if(amount != 0){}   //if the amount isn't 0, then it sends the transaction (unfinished, does nothing right now)
        }

        if(selection == "lock")     //unfinished, but will lock the wallet
        {

        }

        if(selection == "unlock")   //unfinished, but will lock the wallet
        {

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**menu_GUI.h**

```
#ifndef MENU_GUI_H
#define MENU_GUI_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class menu_GUI
{
    public:

        std::string mainMenu();
        std::string askAddress(std::string address);
        int askAmount(int amount);
        void moveCursor(int x, int y);
        void hideCursor();

    private:

        std::vector<std::string> UI {"[Send] ", "Lock ", "Unlock"};
        int rightMoves = 2;
        int leftMoves;
        int inputDelay = 150;   //modify this value to change the delay between user selector movements
        std::string selection;
};

#endif // MENU_GUI_H
```

**menu_GUI.cpp**

```
#include "menu_GUI.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

std::string menu_GUI::mainMenu()
{

    bool selecting = true;

    while(selecting)
    {
        hideCursor();   //hides the cursor

        leftMoves = 2 - rightMoves;     //sets the number of left movements remaining based on right movements remaining

        for(int x = 0, y = 0; x < UI.size(); x++)
        {
            moveCursor(0, 0);
            std::cout << "Balance: ";     //displays users balance
            moveCursor(0, 2);
            std::cout << "Address: ";    //displays users public key

            moveCursor(y, 4);    //prints out the map
            std::cout << UI[x];

            y += UI[x].length();    //sets y equal to the total length accumulated on the line so far
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))      //handles right key inputs
        {
            if(rightMoves != 0)     //check if user can move right
            {
                switch(rightMoves)
                {
                    case 1:
                    rightMoves--;
                    UI[1] = "Lock ";
                    UI[2] = "[Unlock]";
                    break;
                                            //modifies  the UI vector accordingly
                    case 2:
                    rightMoves--;
                    UI[0] = "Send ";
                    UI[1] = "[Lock] ";
                    break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            Sleep(inputDelay);     //Delay, so that user doesn't input twice
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))      //handles right key inputs
        {
            if(leftMoves != 0)     //check if user can move left
            {
                switch(leftMoves)
                {
                    case 1:
                    rightMoves++;
                    UI[0] = "[Send] ";
                    UI[1] = "Lock ";
                    break;
                                            //modifies  the UI vector accordingly
                    case 2:
                    rightMoves++;
                    UI[1] = "[Lock] ";
                    UI[2] = "Unlock";
                    break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            Sleep(inputDelay);     //Delay, so that user doesn't input twice
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))      //handles which selection the user chooses based on how many rightMoves remaining
        {
            system("cls");      //clears the screen, since it's about to display a new page

            switch(rightMoves)
            {
                case 2:
                selection = "send";
                return (selection);
                break;

                case 1:
                selection = "lock";
                return (selection);
                break;

                case 0:
                selection = "unlock";
                return (selection);
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::string menu_GUI::askAddress(std::string address)   //asks user where they wanna send it
{
    std::cout << "Enter where you wanna send the BigBoiCoins. Or type cancel." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: ";
    getline(std::cin, address);     //shouldn't need to check failbit. user input can be anything.

    return address;
}

int menu_GUI::askAmount(int amount)     //asks user how much they wanna send
{
    bool inputting = true;
    while(inputting)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter how many BigBoiCoins you wanna send. Just put 0 if you don't wanna send any." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Amount: ";
        std::cin >> amount;

        if(!std::cin)    //checks failbit to make sure user isn't an idiot and inputs something other than a number
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "who buckaroo! That wasn't a good input. I'll let you try again, I know some of us are special." << std::endl;
        }
        else{inputting = false;}
    }
    return amount;
}

void menu_GUI::moveCursor(int x, int y)     //move the cursor to the desired coords
{
    static const HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    std::cout.flush();
    COORD coord = { (SHORT)x, (SHORT)y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, coord);
}

void menu_GUI::hideCursor()     //hides the cursor
{
   CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info;
   info.dwSize = 100;
   info.bVisible = false;
   SetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &info);
}
```

Comment: You're mixing console input with Win32 APIs that read key states directly. It's already messy.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the heads up, I just started cpp last month, so i'm still learning a lot of the basics. I'll look into what you mean, and figure out how to make it cleaner and more appropriate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some input functions to "eat" some characters. And you'd better use `if(GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x8000)` instead.

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)& 0x8000)      //handles which selection the user chooses based on how many rightMoves remaining
        {
            getline(std::cin,NULL);
            //...
        }
```

and

```
std::cin >> amount;
char c = getchar();//eat '\n'
```

Comment: Yes, and I have posted the specific reasons and details of the principle in another your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973389/having-some-annoying-issues-with-the-cin-buffer/54996608#54996608).